# MSVC Overload error for templates but not g++

Tags: c++

I've asked on other forums but no one has answered :S I keep getting:

> None of the 6 overloads could convert all arguments.

I only get this problem in visual studio though. When I compile with g++ or codeblocks, it works perfectly fine.

The code I'm calling my templates with is:

```
MemDeSerialize(ListOfItems, SerializedData, size_t(Data[2]));
```

The definitions:

```
typedef struct
{
    //......
} PanelItem;

std::vector<PanelItem> ListOfItems;

template<typename T>
void MemDeSerialize(T& Destination, unsigned char* &Source){...}

template<typename T>
void MemDeSerialize(T*& Destination, unsigned char* &Source, size_t Size){...}

template<typename T>
void MemDeSerialize(std::vector<T> &Destination, unsigned char* &Source, size_t Size)
{
    Destination.resize(Size);
    for (size_t I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
        MemDeSerialize(&Destination[I], Source, Size);
}


                                                /** FUNCTION OVERLOADS **/


void MemDeSerialize(Model* Destination, unsigned char* &Source);

void MemDeSerialize(PanelItem* Destination, unsigned char* &Source);

void MemDeSerialize(Compass* Destination, unsigned char* &Source);

void MemDeSerialize(FontChar* Destination, unsigned char* &Source);
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
1>error C2665: 'MemDeSerialize' : none of the 6 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>could be 'void MemDeSerialize<PanelItem>(T *&,unsigned char *&,size_t)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=PanelItem
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(PanelItem *, unsigned char *, size_t)'
1>          see reference to function template instantiation 'void MemDeSerialize<PanelItem>(std::vector<_Ty> &,unsigned char *&,size_t)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=PanelItem
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas why? It compiles fine in codeblocks; just not visual studio.

I've been calling it like so: `MemDeSerialize(ListOfItems, SerializedData, size_t(Data[2]));`

Comment: What are the data types of the arguments in the function call?

Comment: ListOfItems is a vector of PanelItems which is a struct. SerializedData is an unsigned char* and  Data[2] is a double.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: According to the error message, `ListOfItems` is not a vector of `PanelItems` but a `PanelItem *`.

Comment: "None of the 6 overloads"?  I see seven overloads...

Comment: @K-ballo I don't think so. I hover over it, it shows that it's a vector :S The contents of the vector is a PanelItem. I think it's complaining about the vector template overload in the above:

`for (size_t I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
        MemDeSerialize(&Destination[I], Source, Size);
`
But I'm not sure why :S

@aschepler, yes there are 7 overloads. I'm not sure why it says that either :S

It's confusing because g++ compiles it just fine.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Then the error is not where you think it is, but in the overload taking a vector.

Comment: A minimal example that one can take, paste into the own compiler, and experience what you do would be most useful.

Comment: You sure you need that many references to pointers? Casting a double to size_t may also be a logical error. Did you mean `sizeof(Data)` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can't say why it happens but MSVC seems to want you to define a pointer variable to pass as the reference:

```
template<typename T>
void MemDeSerialize(std::vector<T> &Destination, unsigned char* &Source, size_t Size)
{
    Destination.resize(Size);
    for (size_t I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
    {
        T* foo = &Destination[I];
        MemDeSerialize(foo, Source, Size);
    }
}
```

My guess is that passing `&Destination[I]` directly is only giving you the pointer value (address of the element), it doesn't actually give you a pointer variable that you can reference. GCC is perhaps more flexible in allowing you to do that with temporaries.

I don't know what the correct behaviour would be from a standards viewpoint.

Comment: Oh wow.. this actually works!! I can't believe it! Excellent.